# Where can I find "Install Mac OS X Lion" in the App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore, server.app

I'm trying to follow the directions on the Apple Support Page regarding [Mass Deployment](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4746)

Step 2 of the process says

> On the server, install the app named "Install Mac OS X Lion" from the Mac App Store (a network connection is required for this process).

The problem here is that when I do a search for `Install Mac OS X Lion` in the App Store, I get no results found.

Where can I find this app in order to enable me to do mass deployment of OS X Lion across my network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is a copy of the **OS X Lion installer**. If you saved a copy when you first installed Lion, great. If not, you'll need to re-download it from the Mac App Store.

1. Launch the App Store and <kbd>⌥</kbd>-click the Purchases tab. An "Install" button should appear next to Lion. Click it to re-download the installer.
2. Once the installer finishes downloading, go to your Applications folder to find the installer itself. It is called **Install Mac OS X Lion**.

Further steps to get the DMG image:

1. Right-click the installer and choose `Show Package Contents` from the contextual pop-up.
2. Navigate to `.../Contents/SharedSupport`. There you'll find a disk image called `InstallESD.dmg`.

Comment: So maybe their language is wrong on the tutorial? I was looking for an app called `Install OS X Lion` where you're saying I should *install* an app called `OS X Lion`... is that right?

Comment: Yes. The confusion is that the download is called **Install Mac OS X Lion.app** whereas the name in the Mac App Store is **OS X Lion**.

Comment: Nope, the App Store does *not* show the installer when searching for "Lion", "OS X Lion", "OS X Lion.app", "Install Mac OS X Lion", "Mac OS X Lion", or "Install Mac OS X Lion.app". I am choosing "App Store…" from the Apple menu on a Mac running Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

I still see "Mac OS X Lion" on the homepage of the Mac App Store. Can't you see it there?

Did you try to search **Mac OS X Lion** or **Lion**?

---

You can re-download Lion from the App Store by clicking on "Purchase" with the <kbd>alt</kbd> key pressed. Only then will you be able to download. Otherwise, it's just noted as "installed".

---

Do you use the Mac App Store app and not the App Store from iTunes?